# Weird Output in Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I am trying to print the incoming list but i am getting this weird output 
this is one of the functions

```
def printlist(arr,indx,coming_list,sos,target) 
 when indx == length(arr) do
  if sos == target do 
   IO.write coming_list
 end
end
```

output

[image: Output]

I have used IO.inspect i'm getting this

[image: Output]

Now i didn't know how to arrange this coming sublist in a  another list like this
12 => [[2,2,5,3],[4,5,3],[7,2,3]]  like that
 Please help me

Comment: The question is unclear. There seem to be two unrelated questions, one about the strange output (see my answer), one about a desire to transform a list into another list but without a clear requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`IO.write` just outputs the bytes in the list. 2, 3, 4, etc are just control codes in ASCII, hence the strange output.